# passing reference to object c++

Tags: c++

Okay so I'm doing a little for-fun project, I'm an experienced LAMP developer and I decided to mess around with C++

This code is just my attempt at making a working application thats a little bit more difficult than "Hello World" My problem here is in void Defer(). I want to pass a reference to class PoS to my ItemList, so that it can leverage the tax values when returning receipts and calculations

but here is my error that I'm getting:

"ItemList::ItemList(PoS &pos)" provides no initializer for: -- reference member "ItemList::client"

```
class PoS {
    private:
        /*
            States

            0: Main Menu
            1: Order Menu
            2: Edit Menu
            3: Tax Menu
            4: Business Menu
        */
        int State; 
        vector<ItemList> Orders;
        bool IsLiveFlag;
        double Tax = 0.06;

    public:
        PoS() {
            // Constructor
        }
// .......
        void Defer() {

            string Command;

            gotoMain:
            ShowMain();

            cin>>Command;
            if (tolowercase(Command) == "1") {
                ItemList order(*this);
                Orders.push_back(order);

                State = 1;
                Orders[Orders.size() - 1].Defer();
                State = 0;
            }
        }
}


class ItemList {

    private:
        vector<Item> Items;
        double Subtotal;
        double Tendered;
        bool   Paid;
        PoS&   client;
    public:


        ItemList(PoS& pos) {
            Subtotal = 0;
            Tendered = 0;
            Paid     = 0;
            PoS&    client = pos;
        }
```

For some reason I can't get a reference to PoS to send over to my ItemList as a parameter, its really frustrating!

Comment: Seek ye the mighty [Member Initializer list!](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) In C++ all objects must be fully constructed before entering the body of a constructor. Since a reference cannot be reassigned after initialization, you can't `client = pos;`. `PoS&    client = pos;` won't do what you need either. That declared a local variable.

Comment: The definition of `ItemList` needs to be before the usage in `Defer`, not after.

Answer (score 2):

A reference member variable must be initialized before the body of the constructor. That is the meaning of the compiler error message in your post.

Instead of

```
ItemList(PoS& pos) {
    Subtotal = 0;
    Tendered = 0;
    Paid     = 0;
    PoS&    client = pos;
}
```

use

```
ItemList(PoS& pos) : client(pos) {
    Subtotal = 0;
    Tendered = 0;
    Paid     = 0;
}
```

You can improve on it by using the same syntactic form to initialize the other member variables also.

```
ItemList(PoS& pos) : Subtotal(0),
                     Tendered(0),
                     Paid(0),
                     client(pos) {}
```

Comment: Can I ask you WHY I'm using : client(pos), both client and pos are the references I want... of PoS class... I just don't understand it, I don't wanna use the code above and not understand it! I appreciate the answer though but is there any way you can ellaborate a lil more? Whats the syntax for the lines above?

Also, do I have to still define client in the class' scope as a private variable, if I'd like it to be private, is : client(pos) DECLARING the variable? So confused, I'm so sorry guys I came on here with so many questions!

Comment: @user2471817, what do you mean by "I want `... of PoS class ...`?

Comment: Sorry, bad english there on my part! I'll correct it!

Both "client" and "pos" are where I want the references to be contained of PoS

Comment: now I'm getting
 PS C:\cpp\AcePoS> g++ main.cpp
In file included from PoS.h:1:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
ItemList.h:10:9: error: 'PoS' does not name a type
         PoS&   client;
         ^~~